# Kicking off Dataflow Jobs with App Engine errors with a SecurityException on addShutdownHook for BigQueryTableInserter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm attempting to kick of a dataflow job via an (already existing) AppEngine application. The DataFlow job reads data generated by the GAE application stored in DataStore and writes the processed data to BigQuery. I'm receiving the following error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Google App Engine does not support Runtime.addShutdownHook
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-a010d936cef53bc8(Request.java)
at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:46)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.addShutdownHook(MoreExecutors.java:232)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.addDelayedShutdownHook(MoreExecutors.java:204)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$Application.getExitingExecutorService(MoreExecutors.java:188)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.getExitingExecutorService(MoreExecutors.java:89)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableInserter.<clinit>(BigQueryTableInserter.java:79)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$Bound.verifyTableEmpty(BigQueryIO.java:886)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$Bound.apply(BigQueryIO.java:942)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$Bound.apply(BigQueryIO.java:724)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.apply(PipelineRunner.java:74)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:327)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:367)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:274)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:161)
```

Is there a way to enable writing to a BigQuery table in dataflow when being kicked off via GAE? I am setting the runner to `DataflowPipelineRunner`, so it shouldn't be attempting to run it on the GAE instance itself. (Is there a way to verify that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataflowPipelineRunner is attempting to validate your pipeline prior to job submission to the Google Cloud Dataflow service. In this stack trace, we attempt to verify that the destination BigQuery table is empty.

During this process, we initialize an `ExecutorService`, which is not allowed to run in Google App Engine. This is unfortunate, as this is not strictly needed in this scenario. The fix for this is tracked as [BEAM-142](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-142), please check there for any updates.

A workaround would be to disable validation in the App Engine environment. Use `BigQueryIO.Write.withoutValidation()` in your BigQuery sink.

Comment: BEAM-142 has already been resolved for a while, but it seems to me that it hasn't been ported to Dataflow SDK (not even to the `master` branch). Do you know if/when this will happen?

Comment: Hi Helder, unfortunately Dataflow does not support AppEngine standard again -- for critical stability reasons we now rely on some JNI code. As Mete points out, Dataflow jobs can be submitted from App Engine Flex.

Comment: @Dan It's a bit unfortunate that Google is pushing us to use a technology that is still in beta without SLA (AppEngine Flex), while we are running this in production and have SLAs to meet. Thanks anyway for the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can try App Engine Flexible Environment instead which is not as restrictive as App Engine Standard in terms of allowed JRE classes.